# Asp.net's ObjectDataSource data bind event

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource

I'm Working on an Asp.net/C# application.
I want to bind a list of objects to a grid view. 
I've been looking a while to the ObjectDataSource control and it loads data to my datagrid as soon as my page loads. 
Can I change this behaviour? 
For example, how can I set DataBinding only when a button on my page gets clicked?

tks

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into the ObjectDataSource's Selecting event and cancel any selects that don't match the criteria you're looking for.  I do this all the time based on values in other controls.

Look at the e.Cancel property for that event.

Answer (score 1):

Do not set the datasource in markup and simply do it in the code-behind on the OnClick event of the button.

Programatically, you can specify the object to bind to as shown in the answer to this question...

[ASP.NET 2.0: Specifying an instance of an object for an ObjectDataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398231/asp-net-2-0-specifying-an-instance-of-an-object-for-an-objectdatasource/398261)

Comment: This method works for me as well. I described it in my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831208/databind-and-postback/3015512#3015512

Answer (score 0):

You can create the objectdatasource in the code behind and do the bind onclick.

Comment: Bad idea, because you might loose the benefits that you get by using the ODS.